# pre-loading new activities on android

Tags: android

So I was interested in trying out android development in clojure.. and it's well-known that activities take much longer to load than normal java code (~4 seconds for a hello, world). If this was only on app start, it would be acceptable, but the problem is that it's delayed for each new activity that's started, so I was wondering if there was a way to sort of pre-load other activities when the main one is loaded. any ideas?